# Do space suits measure "methane" levels or other biological gases?

Tags: spacesuits, health, medical

A [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36903/was-i-have-the-farts-again-broadcast-from-the-moon-to-the-whole-world#comment117368_36903) below [Was “I have the farts, again” broadcast from the Moon to the whole world?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/36903/12102) links to this [humorous video clip](https://youtu.be/-zhhM2auEYc?t=119) of the 1997 comedy movie *[RocketMan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RocketMan)* about astronauts on Mars. Personnel on the ground discuss the methane level reported in the space suit telemetry.

I would expect that modern, real space suits report things like temperature, pressure and (possibly) humidity, as well as levels of oxygen and CO2, but what about other trace gasses that might indicate a space suit failure or issue, or a medical condition of the occupant? Ketones, methane, or other byproducts of life processes perhaps?

Comment: If they did and I was an astronaut I'd be a blip on the statistics.

Comment: What is the use of a humidity sensor within a space suit when there is nothing to control humidity? The astronaut is exhaling the breathing gas saturated with water vapor at body core temperature, so the suit atmosphere will not be too dry after some minutes of activity. Methane is not toxic, if it is impossible to accumulate more than about 1 % (no risk for ignition or explosion) within the suit, you need no sensor for it.

Comment: Note that there's very little methane in human farts, which are mostly nitrogen from air that got mixed in with your food while you were chewing and swallowing. And, while we're on the subject, cows' guts do a lot of fermenting so they produce a lot more methane, but it's mostly belched rather than farted.

Comment: @DavidRicherby cite your source (seriously); here's mine: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5GDLGaaL80 (lower your volume first) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fart_lighting

Comment: @uhoh Suarez, Furne, Springfield and Levitt, [Insights into human colonic physiology obtained from the study of flatus composition](https://www.physiology.org/doi/pdf/10.1152/ajpgi.1997.272.5.G1028), _Gastrointestinal and Liver Physiology_, 272(5):G1028-G1033, 1997. Three of the 16 subjects passed about 25% methane, but eleven passed less than 0.01%. On average, the major components were CO2 (34.7%), hydrogen(!) (34.3%), nitrogen (22.2%), methane (5.6%) and oxygen (3.3%). So I was wrong about nitrogen, but most people seem to have almost no methane.

Comment: @DavidRicherby okay so *most* farts contain no methane, but some farts do. It sounds like there is substantial variation between individuals (which makes sense considering there's microbiome variation) and the possibility of fart-to-fart variation as well. But what I found the most interesting is your mention of "hydrogen(!)" [1](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/80302/27918), [2](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16577/6031), [3](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/16890/6031) I wonder if the color of the flames can be used to distinguish between H2 and CH4 dominant farts?

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'm thinking that the yellow flames indicate soot and therefore carbon; hydrogen flames are notoriously [hard to see](https://h2tools.org/bestpractices/hydrogen-flames). So the video is likely showing methane combustion with the bright yellow flames.

Comment: Don't forget that space suits are pressurised, any failure of the suit will vent gasses to the external "atmosphere" with little chance of anything coming in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The US's only "modern, real" space suit, the Extravehicular Mobility Unit (EMU), was designed in the 1970s.  It has a very limited sensor suite and no [automation](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10475/6944) at all.

The only sensors used in the suit are

- A biomedical harness (with electrocardiograph electrodes)
- A carbon dioxide (CO2) partial pressure sensor
- A total pressure sensor
- ventilation flow sensor (an on/off sensor)
- feedwater supply pressure sensors
- feedwater pressure sensor
- O2 tank pressure sensor
- secondary oxygen pack pressure sensor
- sublimator outlet temperature sensor
- battery voltage
- battery current
- motor RPM and voltage
- switch positions

There is also a purely mechanical total pressure gauge.

[image]

[source](https://archive.org/details/EMUSystemsWorkbookJSC19450B)

Comment: Note that astronauts don't tend to spend prolonged times in space suits so the risk of asphyxiating on their own farts is extremely unlikely.  Even back in the Apollo days, crew members didn't wear helmets or gloves while inside the CM.

Comment: @Snow the longest EVA I'm aware of was just shy of 9 hours (Voss & Helms, STS-102)

Comment: Still, it would take a pretty extreme stomach complaint to raise the stink levels to fatally toxic amounts on an EVA of that length...

Comment: Wow I am really surprised! So the only telemetry potentially available about the astronaut's conditions (excluding self-reporting) is total pressure and CO2 partial pressure, and the astronaut's EKG. Is the "sublimator outlet temperature sensor" measuring the temperature of cold air or water being returned to the suit, or the water vapor being sublimated into space?

Comment: @uhoh it's the temperature of the cooling water as it exits the sublimator (p. 3-22 in the linked reference)

Comment: [Here's an Apollo 9 bioharness](http://www.collectspace.com/ubb/Forum14/HTML/001358.html) that measures oxygen and temperature. [More bioharness ino](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-368/s6ch3.htm).  However, I can't easily find bioharness details for the later shuttle missions.

Comment: @Snow the shuttle bioharness was ECG only.  https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/188963main_Extravehicular_Mobility_Unit.pdf Good details on the Apollo harness here https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19760003073.pdf